# Create a command accepting arbitrary text

Tags: macros

How can I create a new command that accepts all its text as single argument?

The closest example is `\textcolor{red}{arbitrary, text, with, commas}`

I would like to declare a similar command.

Comment: You can define a command as `\newcommand*{\dnfoo}[1]{X#1Y}` and use it: `\dnfoo{arbitrary, text, with, commas}`. Whether the input can be arbitrary depends on what you want to do with the argument.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe the `[1]` (specifying your macro only accepts one argument) is what you need ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of application.

```
 \documentclass[]{article}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \newcommand{\mytext}[1]{{\bfseries #1}}
 \begin{document}

      \lipsum[1] 
      \mytext{\lipsum[2]}
      \lipsum[3] 

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you remove the `[1]` in the definition of `\mytext` the compiler returns an error.